# Curious Sharepoint Response - Modified not working correctly with OData query operations ge and lt in request?

Tags: rest, sharepoint

I have the following curious behaviour of Sharepoint-REST-API.

I send the following request via Postman to Sharepoint REST-Webservice (REST-API v1):

```
.../lists/GetByTitle('Documents')/items?$select=FileLeafRef,GUID,ID,Modified,FileRef,FileSizeDisplay&$filter=Modified ge datetime'2023-07-30T00:00:00Z' and Modified lt datetime'2023-11-23T00:00:00Z' and FSObjType+eq+0 and GUID eq '3b0fd751-9c3e-48dd-9588-1b8eae918f90'&$orderby=ID asc
```

and we get the following response:

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "Id": 257,
            "Modified": "2019-02-07T07:58:01Z",
            "FileLeafRef": "DOXiS4-SmartOfficePlus_V0800_845-D-E_CD.iso",
            "ID": 257,
            "FileRef": "/teams/db.systel.einheit-bcm/Shared Documents/Technik/SER Software/DOXiS4 SmartOfficePlus/Aeltere_Versionen/DOXiS4-SmartOfficePlus_V0800_845-D-E_CD.iso",
            "FileSizeDisplay": "409964544",
            "GUID": "3b0fd751-9c3e-48dd-9588-1b8eae918f90"
        }
    ]
}
```

In my opinion we should only get documents with Modified between 2023-07-30T00:00:00Z and 2023-11-23T00:00:00Z and that works in the most cases. But here we get the resulting document above with Modified-value 2019-02-07T07:58:01Z. Why? Do I misunderstand something in using Modified with the operations ge/lt?

I have tried the request from above with the following results:

```
Modified ge datetime'2023-03-31T00:00:00Z' and Modified lt datetime'2023-07-31T00:00:00Z' --> no document found
Modified ge datetime'2023-07-31T00:00:00Z' and Modified lt datetime'2023-08-01T00:00:00Z' --> document from above found
Modified ge datetime'2023-08-01T00:00:00Z' and Modified lt datetime'2023-11-23T00:00:00Z' --> no document found
```

I don't know, if this information helps.

----------- UPDATE -----------

I have removed Modified from indexed colums and added it again. The filtering works now correctly, Modified-filtering works as expected. How can this happen, that the indexed values are wrong or not uptodate? Can this relate with an exceeded list view threshold? The list, I'm talking about, exceeds the list view threshold

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have removed Modified from indexed colums and added it again. The filtering works now correctly, Modified-filtering works as expected. How can this happen, that the indexed values are wrong or not uptodate? Can this relate with the exceeded list view threshold?